# How do I connect Locust workers to a master running with an https URL?

Tags: locust

My company writes medical software and as such is subject to the HIPPA requirments.  We are running our code in GCP and I am trying to implement load testing using Locust.

I am able to get the locust master up and running on one of our clusters with an external address but only via https://locustmaster.gcp.mycompany

I am trying to figure out how to get the workers to connect to this.  There are TLS and web auth command line options but those are for connecting to the target URL and not the locust master.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Oh, I am using Locust V1.4.4.

Answer (score 3):

Worker and master communicate over ZeroMQ (unfortunately they cant work over http). You point to the master using `--master-host=X.X.X.X` and `--master-port=XYZ`

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-distributed.html#options

Comment: Hi @cyberwiz  I have been reading your answers on locust, really thanks for all that help.

Comment: Thanks @joseph adam!